# Transforming a Lognormal mean and SD into normal mean and SD

Tags: python, numpy, distribution

I have the mean and the SD from a log normal distribution. However, in order to provide a sampling with  from a log-normal distribution in python I need to transfer these variables into a the mean and SD of the underlying Normal distribution.

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import normal
import numpy as np
mu = 25.2
sigma = 10.5
#pd.reset_option('display.float_format')
r = []
r = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1000)
for i in range(1000):
    while r[i] > 64 or r[i] < 4:
        y = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 1)   
        r[i] = y[0]

df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns = ['Column_A'])
print(df)
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})
sns.set(rc={"figure.figsize": (8, 4)})
sns.distplot(df['Column_A'], bins = 70)
```

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQQu6.png)

[And this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlLf5.png)

However, I don't know how to transfer these values

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your post, you want to access to the underlying `(mu sigma^2)` parametrization of the normal distribution that produced your log-normal observations ?

## TL;DR

Assuming your log-normal observations are stored in `r`:

```py
mu = np.log(np.median(r))
var = 2*(np.log(np.mean(r)) - np.log(np.median(r)))
sd = np.sqrt(var)
```

## Theoretical part

Start reading [ref](/questions/tagged/ref) [some statistics about log-normal distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Log-normal_distribution). It appears it's quite hard to retrieve `(mu, sigma^2)` from the empirical mean and variance of a log-normal sample ...
Let `X` be a log-normal random variable and let `Y=ln(X)`. It appears `Y` follows a normal distribution with mean `(mu, sigma^2)`. Let `M` ans `S` be the mean and variance of `X`. It turns out that:

```
M = exp(mu + sigma^2/2)
S = (exp(sigma^2) - 1) * exp(2*mu + sigma^2)
```

Which hardly leads to a simple expression for `(mu, sigma^2)`.

However, according to [ref](/questions/tagged/ref), inverting your (M, S) system will be easier by replacing the variance `S` by either the median `Med` or the mode `Mode` since they hold a much simpler expression wrt `(mu, sigma^2)`:

```
Med = exp(mu)
Mode = exp(mu - sigma^2)
```

The empirical median will be easier to compute through Numpy so let's assume we'll use it in our computations. The inverted system should lead to the following estimators for `(mu, sigma^2)`:

```
mu = log(Med)
sigma2 = 2*(log(M) - log(Med))
```

## Pythonic part

Supposing your log-normal observations are stored in your `r` array:

```py
mu = np.log(np.median(r))
var = 2*(np.log(np.mean(r)) - np.log(np.median(r)))
sd = np.sqrt(var)
```

And a quick-check shows it's likely to be right :

```py
# random log-normal sample with (mu, sigma)=(1, 2)
r = np.random.lognormal(1, 2, size=(1000000))
# estimators
mu = np.log(np.median(r))
var = 2*(np.log(np.mean(r)) - np.log(np.median(r)))
sd = np.sqrt(var)

$> mu = 1.001368782773
$> sigma = 2.0024723139
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Now I get the result!